# C++ Trie Core Dumped Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, trie

I was solving the following question from Facebook Hacker Cup:

> Since you crave state-of-the-art technology, you've just purchased a phone with a great new feature: autocomplete! Your phone's version of autocomplete has some pros and cons. On the one hand, it's very cautious. It only autocompletes a word when it knows exactly what you're trying to write. On the other hand, you have to teach it every word you want to use.
>
> You have N distinct words that you'd like to send in a text message in order. Before sending each word, you add it to your phone's dictionary. Then, you write the smallest non-empty prefix of the word necessary for your phone to autocomplete the word. This prefix must either be the whole word, or a prefix which is not a prefix of any other word yet in the dictionary.
>
> What's the minimum number of letters you must type to send all N words?

I am implementing a trie for this as follows:

```
    struct trie {
    int ct;
    vector<trie*> child;
    trie() {
        ct = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            child.push_back(nullptr);
        }
    }
    ~trie() {
        //cerr << "called\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            delete child[i];
        }
        child.clear();

    }

};


void add(trie* t, const string &str, int i) {
    //ct++;
    int index = str[i] - 'a';
    if(t->child[index] == nullptr) {
        t->child[index] = new trie();
    }
    t->child[index]->ct++;
    i++;
    if(i != str.length()) {
        add(t->child[index], str, i);
    }
}

int getL(trie* t, const string &str, int i) {

    if(i == str.length()) {
        return i;
    }
    int index = str[i] - 'a';
    if(t->child[index]->ct == 1) {
        return i + 1;
    }
    else {
        return getL(t->child[index], str, i + 1);
    }
}

int solve() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string s;
    //cin >> s;
    int i;
    trie* root = new trie();
    int ans = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> s;
        cerr << "READ "  << s << '\n';
        add(root, s, 0);
        cerr << "DONE ADD\n";
        ans += getL(root, s, 0);
    }
    //int ans = 0;
    delete (root);
    return ans;

}
```

However I seem to be getting Segmentation fault(Core Dumped) error which I understand means that I am accessing an invalid memory location however I cannot seem to figure out where it is the case in my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of input caused the crash? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: A very very large string(< 10^6 though) input caused the error. But the error was segmentation fault which is indicative of invalid memory access hence I looked many times at my code for invalid memory access but can't find one. It would be impractical to copy the exact string here. But it seems to be working on smaller inputs which got me perplexed and wonder that it might be a memory leak issue, although deleting as done does not help either.

Comment: Analyzing code is nice way, but current case is better to solve with debugger. What toolchain do you use? Can you get stack trace for failure scenario?